# Keras Sequential model input: How significant are the dimensions?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a multioutput classifier on 3D data structured like `[sampleID, timestamp, deviceID, sensorID]` with one-hot labels like `[sampleID, deviceID]` to determine which device "wins".

In a nutshell, it is a massive collection of timeseries readings from five sensors taken at regular intervals from each of four different devices. The objective is to determine which of the devices is most likely to be in a particular state at the end of each `sampleID`. The labels are a one-hot representation of the devices.

In a case like this where a human would find meaning in the structure of the dataset, does the training process derive similar benefit? Can I simplify my dataset by reducing it to `[dataset, deviceID, timestamp X sensor]` or even `[dataset, deviceID X timestamp X sensor]` and still get similar accuracy?

In other words would simplifying the following dataset:
`[10000, 1000, 4, 5]`
down to
`[10000, 4, 5000]`
or
`[10000, 1000, 20]`
or even
`[10000, 20000]`
significantly diminish the model's ability to classify output?

*Edited to for detail and formatting.*

Comment: When you say your inputs are [10000,100,4,5] and labels are [10000,4], what do those mean? So, as per my understanding - `[reading instances, batch of readings, ?, sensors]` ? an i right? can you elaborate more? also, what in the same way, what are the labels? and, whats the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Updated question with requested info.

Comment: Thanks, will look into it!

Comment: The deviceID is already part of the input, whats the goal of predicting the deviceID as the output?

Comment: The goal is to predict which one of the deviceIDs is the "winner" in terms of performance.

Comment: There is not way to actually determine whether the first or second case will be better. But, you can test it out easy. I have writting some sample code for your reference below. If you consider the 20 sensors individually, you can simply use a LSTM based model and let the model handle the non linear relationships between them.

Comment: For second case, you have to consider 4x5 as spatial dimensions and 1000 as temporal dims/channels. This will then require a Conv-LSTM model, where you convolve over the spatial dims first and then flatten the spatial dims to work on the temporal axis with an LSTM.

Comment: Do check out both the sample codes I have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you are asking if using 1000 timesteps for 20 objects (device X sensor) is better than using 1000 timesteps for 4 devices for 5 sensors.

There is no way of actually determining which would better model your problem, but, we can quickly build some tests to see which models capture the complexity of the problem better.

---

**Case 1: 1000 time steps, 20 objects -> Sequential LSTM based model**

If you consider the 20 sensors individually, you can simply use a LSTM based model and let the model handle the non linear relationships between them. Since you have a 2D input, simply build reshape your data and build a model in the following structure. Feel free to add more layers and activations etc.

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model, utils

#Temporal model

inp = layers.Input((1000,20))
x = layers.LSTM(30, return_sequences=True)(inp)
x = layers.LSTM(30)(x)
out = layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inp, out)

model.summary()
```

```
Model: "model_4"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_6 (InputLayer)         [(None, 1000, 20)]        0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_4 (LSTM)                (None, 1000, 30)          6120      
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_5 (LSTM)                (None, 30)                7320      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_20 (Dense)             (None, 4)                 124       
=================================================================
Total params: 13,564
Trainable params: 13,564
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

---

**Case 2: 1000 time steps, 4x5 objects -> Conv-LSTM based model**

Since you have a 3D input, you want to consider the 4x5 as your spatial axes and your 1000 as your channels/feature maps/temporal features. Since your data type has `channels_first`, do specify them in the `Conv2D` as well as `MaxPooling2D` layers.

Then, once you have convolved over the spatial axes, you can start working on the feature maps with an LSTM. Sample code below, feel free to modify and build on top of this.

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model, utils

#Conv-LSTM model

inp = layers.Input((1000,4,5))
x = layers.Conv2D(30,2, data_format="channels_first")(inp)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(2, data_format="channels_first")(x)
x = layers.Reshape((-1,2))(x)
x = layers.LSTM(20)(x)
out = layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inp, out)

model.summary()
```

```
Model: "model_21"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_25 (InputLayer)        [(None, 1000, 4, 5)]      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_19 (Conv2D)           (None, 30, 3, 4)          120030    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_14 (MaxPooling (None, 30, 1, 2)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_10 (Reshape)         (None, 30, 2)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_19 (LSTM)               (None, 20)                1840      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_30 (Dense)             (None, 4)                 84        
=================================================================
Total params: 121,954
Trainable params: 121,954
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```